# laravel and swiftmail shows Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified]

Tags: php, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I am writing an app that send mail to the client using laravel and swiftmailer but I get Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.] error.

Here is my code

env settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USERNAME = "*********"
MAIL_PASSWORD = *******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls
```

controller

```
 $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");
 Mail::send('emails.mail', $data, function($message) {
     $message->to('chuditex2004@yahoo.com', 'Tutorials Point')->subject
           ('Laravel HTML Testing Mail');
              $message->from('chuksdsilent@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
           });
           echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
```

Log

> Swift_TransportException: Process could not be started [The system
>   cannot find the path specified. ] in file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php
>   on line 299 Stack trace:
>     1. Swift_TransportException->() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:299
>     2. Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishProcessConnection() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:58
>     3. Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:126
>     4. Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\SendmailTransport.php:52
>     5. Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport->start() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php:67
>     6. Swift_Mailer->send() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:451
>     7. Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:235
>     8. Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:221
>     9. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade->__callStatic() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\app\Http\Controllers\APIController.php:120
>    10. App\Http\Controllers\APIController->sendEmail() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
>    11. call_user_func_array() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
>    12. Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:45
>    13. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:212
>    14. Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:169
>    15. Illuminate\Routing\Route->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:658
>    16. Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
>    17. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php:41
>    18. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    19. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    20. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php:57
>    21. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    22. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    23. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:102
>    24. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:660
>    25. Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:635
>    26. Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:601
>    27. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:590
>    28. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:176
>    29. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
>    30. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php:56
>    31. Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    32. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    33. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:30
>    34. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    35. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    36. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:30
>    37. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    38. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    39. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php:27
>    40. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    41. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    42. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
>    43. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>    44. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>    45. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:102
>    46. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:151
>    47. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
>    48. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle() C:\xampp\htdocs\tranxavApi\public\index.php:55

Comment: I think you are having the same issue as here: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/1080#issuecomment-381207644

Answer (score 1):

This problem can generally occur when you do not enable two step verification for the gmail account (which can be done here) you are using to send an email. So first, enable two step verification, you can find plenty of resources for enabling two step verification. After you enable it, then you have to create an app password. And use the app password in your .env file. When you are done with it, your .env file will look something like.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and your mail.php

```
<?php

return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => '<<your email>>', 'name' => '<<any name>>'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,

];
```

After doing so, run php artisan config:cache and php artisan config:clear, then check, email should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because the SwiftMailer ignored the correct environment from the `.env` file.

But changing the

`'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),`

to

`'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),`

in the `/config/mail.php` fixed the problem for me.

Apparently the `mail` driver is deprecated in the SwiftMailer since version 5.4.5 and it caused the driver to change to `sendmail` even though I had it set as `smtp` in my .env.